# PVA bot not responding for some colleagues in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, chatbot, power-automate, azure-openai, power-virtual-agents

I created a chatbot in Power Virtual Agents that uses a Power Automate Flow to query ChatGPT on Azure OpenAI service, and connects PVA to OpenAI to produce the responses. I published the PVA bot to Teams through the 'Show to everyone in my org'. This has been **approved by the admin**, and is **showing under 'Built by your org' in my colleagues Teams**. However, when they Add the bot, it **does not respond to messages or send the PVA 'Conversation Start' message**.

The bot is however responding in Teams for myself and one other colleague. (I have added it to a different account than the one I created the PVA bot under, and this works). However, it has stopped sending a greeting message when opening the bot, e.g 'Hello, how can I help'?

The flow is working correctly, as is the Fallback topic in PVA. We have the correct permission policies to allow custom apps and Power Platform apps in Teams, and all colleagues have permission.

Any ideas as to why this is not responding or sending the conversation start message for certain colleagues?

Troubleshooting/resolutions I have tried (with no luck):

- Uninstalling and re-adding bot.
- Start over prompt.

Comment: Could you please check for any error messages or logs in the PVA, Power Automate Flow, or Azure OpenAI service that could provide insights into why the bot is not responding.
As you mention issue is happening with some colleagues, Could you please check the teams version as well which same as you or not.